# Is an areligious person secular?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, connotation

An [areligious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/areligious) person is one who is:

> unconcerned with or indifferent to religious matters.

A [secular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularity) person is one who is:

> in the state of being separate from religion, or not being exclusively allied or against any particular religion.

Do these words refer to the same beliefs?

Also, are the connotations of each of these words the same? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 2):

***Areligious*** has the same structure as "amoral" = indifferently moral. Nature is considered amoral. So Areligious, as the link you gave describes, means unconcerned about religion one way or the other. ***Secular*** (L. saecularis) on the other hand is different, but related.  Saecularis may have several meanings (I think), but *separated* is the primary one. So a secular person is separate from or not for or against any particular religion. Here it overlaps with ***agnostic***.  To use them interchangeably would require a larger context. For instance, one rendition might be: In a secular state citizens may be religious or areligious, but the state government itself must be formally non-religious."